# Appcelerator Titanium: How to use the onLoad event of an Window?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

```
mainWin.pageLoad=false;
mainWin.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  if(mainWin.pageLoad) {
    mainWin.open();    
     } else {
      mainWin.close();    
      var LoginWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
        title : 'Login',  
        url:'Login.js'   
      });
   LoginWindow.open();
  }
});
```

This is my app.js file. If the pageLoad variable holds the boolean value true, then i need to navigate to mainWin `{Which is the current Window}` else i need to go to Login Page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    var LoginWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow ({
      backgroundColor:'#1E563F',
      url:'Login.js',
    });


    mainWin.addEventListener('open', checkPage);
        mainWin.pageLoad = false;

        function checkPage() {  
           if(mainWin.pageLoad) {
             mainWin.open();
           } else {
             mainWin.close();
             LoginWindow.open();
           }
        }

  mainWin.open();
```

This should work....

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put your code like this ?

```
mainWin.pageLoad = false;
mainWin.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  if(mainWin.pageLoad) {
    mainWin.open();    
   } else {
      mainWin.close();    
      var LoginWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
        title : 'Login',  
        url:'Login.js'   
      });
   LoginWindow.open();
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your way, have updated my code too... but everytime it loads mainWin.open() irrespective of the boolen value changed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is probably that the the variable is updated to true before the event is dispatched. Did you try to print to console the mainWin.pageLoad value?
Where do you update the variable to true?

Answer (score 1):

try using the `focus` event instead of the load event.

Comment: then can i suggest you post all your code to a pastie because either or the two approaches described here should work so the problem must lie elsewhere